# Why is Bundle Optimizations causing CSS Issues with Input Groups?

Tags: css, .net, asp.net-mvc, less

I'm using a MVC 5 and bootstrap 3 as to design a simple form.

[image: Code]

[image: Inputs]

For some reason, when I EnableOptimizations in the bundleconfig to be true, the CSS shows up as the above. There is a gap in between.

However, if I set EnableOptimizations to false, it works fine and the input field extends to the right side properly.

I'm using LESS if that helps.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you also use some custom css/less? could you show your bundle config too?

Comment: Seems that you have minification issue. Check if all required CSS files are arranged properly, avoid using minified version files as style sources when `EnableOptimizations` is enabled. Show your HTML output on both `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true` and `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false` if necessary.